# Running Powershell FOR loop with Invoke Rest Method

Tags: powershell, date, for-loop

I am trying to run Powershell script with Invoke RestMethod. This Rest Method has startdate and enddate parameters which will start running from 2022-02-01 till 2023-07-23 for every day and produce that day specific file. So this has to run fro almost 500 days in loop with 500 JSON files created with that particular date in file name.

I have created a script but my problem here is to pass the new value to startdate after every loop and create the file with the new startdate variable. THis should continue until the startdate variable is less than enddate variable.Please find the script below

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
$startdate = Get-Date '2022-02-01'
$enddate = Get-Date '2022-02-05'
$startdate_out = ($startdate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$enddate_out = ($enddate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Write-Output $startdate
Write-Output $startdate_out
Write-Output $enddate
Write-Output $enddate_out

for($i = $startdate; $i -le $enddate; $i = $i.AddDays(1))
{
$body = @"
{`"reportRequests`":[{`"viewId`":`"208332827`",`"dateRanges`":[{`"endDate`":`"$startdate_out`",`"startDate`":`"$startdate_out`"}],`"metrics`":[{`"expression`":`"ga:pageviews`"}],`"dimensions`":[{`"name`":`"ga:socialNetwork`"}]}]}
"@

$body | ConvertTo-Json -depth 3
##$body_out = ConvertTo-Json $body

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?access_token=ya29.a0AfB_byBldik1w9dL049j4DThmhe6GDUYzYM1d2EmgvTARoF97mALw8NxYo4gnRvQd8SkYZJDlQWTlI0EjJeXm4PSW094dWb_871DIvE6nqE9DgQ2HCfRnAKysLbwXMBRjS8e07Q2tk2TW2BFPBmyK9QZF67T6IkcrgChaCgYKAdgSARISFQGOcNnC6Ex6h7N3dTDiR583VzqVZQ0171' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | Set-Content Z:\Informatica\IICS\ProjectFolders\Dev\Government\Google_Analytics\Files\GA_PageViews_SocialNetworks_$startdate_out.json

continue

}

$startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
$startdate_out = ($startdate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Write-Output $startdate
```

Please any suggestions on how to pass the updated startdate variable to beginning of loop everytime it runs until the condition is satisfied

I tried to run the powershell script in for loop with the startdate variable getting added each day and passing to the Invoke RestMethod.
I am not able to pass the Startdate variable to the beginning of loop.

Comment: please clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to increment the $startdate by 1 day and run the Invoke restmethod in loop until the loop conditon is satisfied which is $startdate<$enddate. So for first run the $startdate will be 2022-02-01, after first loop run the $startdate should be set to +1 day which is 2022-02-02 and the loop should continue. THis will run like this until the date is greater than 2022-01-05 which $enddate. I want to caluclate the $startdate at end of loop everytime and pass to the next loop run. Current code is running from 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-05, but the $startdate is not getting incremented.

Comment: Use `for( ; $startdate -le $enddate; $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1))` - or leave your loop as is and use `$i` instead of startdate.

Comment: also you never make use of `$startdate` - I see just `$startdate_out` being used

Comment: Hi Yacc, This is working absolutely fine, thanks for your help. We can close this.